# Transitioning from For Loops to ForEach, with examples

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to become better at Javascript and I got my first challenge, move from For Loops to something else, in this case ForEach, but I can't figure how to do it, for example:

For Loop (WORKING)

```
colors = ['red','yellow','green','blue'];
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
for(i=0;i<li.length;i++){
    li[i].style.color = colors[i];
};
```

ForEach (WORKING)

```
Array.from(li).forEach((element) => element.style.color = 'red')
```

Another way to do it:

```
li = [...document.getElementsByTagName('li')]
li.forEach((element) => element.style.color = 'blue')
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns HTMLCollection that doesn't have forEach method. 
Use Array.from(li).forEach((element) => element.style.color = 'red')

Comment: Thank you for your help, honestly I never read anything like this in the 3 books I have about JavaScript! :)

Comment: or `let li = [...document.getElementsByTagName('li')]`

Comment: the javascript books you read must not have any reference to browser DOM then and what different DOM functions return ... i.e HTMLCollection, vs NodeList vs Array :p